# What is the meaning of line breaks in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Stored procedure like this works

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AllotTectOnBay] 
      @date datetime,
      @AddTech [dbo].[AddTechnicianBayallotment] READONLY 
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     begin try
     begin transaction

     commit transaction
     end try
     BEGIN CATCH
         rollback transaction;
         declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max), @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int;

         select 
             @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + '' Line '' + cast (ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(5)), 
             @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
             @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(); 

         raiserror (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState); 
     END CATCH
 END
 GO
```

But when I put everything on one line it doesn't work. Why? Does SQL Server have anything like line end ; in C#?

Comment: try to separate the commands with GO before put everything into one line

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be on `GO` command. It must be put in a single line (and maybe include comments)

> A Transact-SQL statement cannot occupy the same line as a GO command. However, the line can contain comments.

Reference link: [MDSN GO COMMAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)

From `ALTER` to `END` of stored procedure you can put it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can also define your sql statements in multiple lines.

```
string sqlCommand = @"select * from foobar
                      where ....";
```